# Does Active Record have has_and_belongs_to_one association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `Staff` table and a `Store` table, but each store has up to one manager, and each staff can manage up to one store.

To avoid [multivalued dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_normal_form) in 4NF. I want to create a `StoreManager` table in contrast to another `StoreStaffs` table which stores information about staffs and the store they work in..

Nevertheless, `Store` and `Staff` has a **one-to-one** relationship through `StoreManager` table.

Although Rails has `has_and_belongs_to_many` association, in my case, it will not apply but `has_and_belongs_to_one` is needed instead.

So is there a possible relationship similar to `has_and_belongs_to_one` in Rails' Active Record?

Comment: I'm confused why you wouldn't just set this up as a `belongs_to` relationship. `Store belongs_to Staff`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `has_one` and `has_one :through`.

Following is some pseudo code:

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :store_manager
  has_one :staff, through: :store_manager
end

class StoreManager < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :store
end

class Staff < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

Refer to [ActiveRecord::Associations#has_one](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_one) for more info.

Comment: The example you gave me is a has_many :through. Can you modify it so I can mark it accepted?